# error: expected '{' before '_GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY' namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)

Tags: qt, android-ndk

I am using pre-compiled Qt 5.2.1 for Android Application in Windows 7-64 bit. I am not able to build a simple Hello World program on cpu armeabi-v7a.I am using android_armv7 compiler.
Earlier I was getting this error-  error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory

Then I added the below path to my .pro file-

INCLUDEPATH += C:/android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r9d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include \ + C:\QtMobile\Tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\i686-w64-mingw32

Now,I am getting the below error-
C:\android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r9d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include\bits\stl_relops.h:67: error: expected '{' before '_GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY'
 namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)

I tried to search everywhere but I am not getting the solution.Please help me out.

Comment: I don't know if qt already supports Android if not you need to drop your plans. Btw what is your reason to write the UI with qt and not the normal java/xml way?

Comment: Qt Mobile is newly launched which has Qt Creator 5.2.1.Its mentioned that it supports Android and IOS. It supports C++ and QML which I am familiar with.I wanted to use the latest version of Qt as I am comfortable in using it

Comment: I got the solution.It was the problem of ndk version.But if I am using Qt Creator 5.2.1 for API 19,I am not able to deploy it on the device.For API 18 its working well.. Thank you. :)

Comment: Please remember to write this as answer. So you can earn reputation ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.It was the problem of ndk version.But if I am using Qt Creator 5.2.1 for API 19,I am not able to deploy it on the device.For API 18 its working well.. Thank you. :)

Comment: I was using NDK for 64 bit instead of 32 bit.So i was not able to compile for my arm kit which is 32 bit.When I used ndk for x86,it worked. Thank you :)